# Displaying Specific Database Value into Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database. Namely ***food_dish*** and ***foodcat***. Food dish is for the dishes while foodcat is for the categories of the food.

Here's an example of what is inside food_dish:

`dish_id |  dish name |  dish_cat
   1     | Plain Rice | 1 
   2     | Pork Chop  | 2
   3     | Buttered Rice | 1`

and in foodcat:

`cat_id | cat_name
   1    | Rice
   2    | Pork`

I want to display in my ***menurice.php*** table only the plain rice. I want to find out if I can link the ***dish_cat*** to the ***cat_id*** so when I call ***cat_id 1*** it'll only show the names of the ***Rices***.

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
 <thead>
 <tr>           
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Dish Name</th>
 <th> Actions </th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php
 include 'menuactions/foodconnect.php';
 $sql1= "SELECT * FROM `food_dish`";
 $data= mysqli_query($conn,$sql1) or die("Connection Failed!");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 ?>

 <tr class="odd gradeX">
 <td> <?php echo $row['dish_id']?> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $row['dish_name']?>  </td>                                    
 <td> 

 <div class='btn-group'>
 <form action='deleterice.php' method='POST'>
  <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'><a class='fa fa-trash-o'> Delete</a></button>
          <input type='hidden' value=" <?php echo $row['dish_id'];?>" name="iduse">
           </form>
         </div>
       </td>
       </tr>

         <?php 
     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you mean, when you go to `menurice.php?cat_id=1` it should only show Rices?

Use this query: `SELECT * FROM food_dish WHERE dish_cat = ?` and bind `$_GET['cat_id']` to the query.

For example:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT dish_id, dish_name FROM food_dish WHERE dish_cat = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_GET['cat_id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $dish_id, $dish_name);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    ?>

<tr class="odd gradeX">
  <td> <?php echo $dish_id; ?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $dish_name; ?> </td>
  <td>
    <div class='btn-group'>
      <form action='deleterice.php' method='POST'>
        <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'><a class='fa fa-trash-o'> Delete</a></button>
        <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $dish_id; ?>" name="iduse">
      </form>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: I get error `mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean`

Comment: @EllisCristoph My mistake, I used `cat_id` in the query instead of `dish_cat`. Try the updated code. The URL is still `menurice.php?cat_id=1`, change the 1 to a 2 to see the differences.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '"Prepare error:"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` I get a new error.

Comment: Yup just remove that if-statement and the die statement. Check the edited code.

Comment: Awesome! Also I deleted a space from the beginning of `value=" <?php echo $dish_id; ?>"` so now it is `value="<?php echo $dish_id; ?>"`. I think that should make your deleterice.php work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use the name from `foodcat` table to display instead of the name from `food_dish` table.

So you could use `inner join` or `union` command. The follow sql command will work:

```
SELECT food_dish.dish_id as id,foodcat.cat_name as name from food_dish inner join foodcat on instr(food_dish.dish_name,foodcat.cat_name)>0
```

It will yield the following outcome:
id name
1  Rice
2  Pork
3  Rice

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. This query links dish_cat to the cat_id and returns dish names only if both dish_cat and cat_id are equal.

```
SELECT food_dish.`dish name` FROM food_dish, foodcat 
WHERE cat_id = 1 AND (food_dish.dish_cat = foodcat.cat_id);
```

Pass the cat_id value of your choice here.

The above query outputs the rice names for cat_id 1:

**dish name**

Plain Rice

Buttered Rice

Comment: How do I put this on my bootstrap table? It gives me a "connection failed" error.

Comment: @EllisCristoph Put the query in your code and insert echo variable enclosed in a <td> element to display in a bootstrap table. Share more details of your "connection failed" error if you haven't figured it out yet.